# Getting blank page in spring application and after cleaning browser cache it works fine

Tags: java, spring

I have created one spring application and it worked fine before one day but today I have made some changes and now I am running the application but when I click on any link (any action) it shows the blank page.
And if I clean the cache of the browser it works fine.
I haven't used any chache in application.
Don't understand what is the problem, is it with browser or with coding????

Comment: Its a big application so don't have any idea that which code gives such type of error??

Comment: After every request I need to clean the history and then it works fine for only that request and so on

Answer (score 0):

I think blank page is coming due to browser cache. As you have told that you have changed many things, so it might be like that browser is expecting few resources as per its cache records but you have already changed many things so it doesn't have any response to show.
You should configure the Error code 404 properly, so browser can simply show you the error that it is unable to find the resource.

Comment: Also, if you have not handled error code 404, and you are asking for some non-existing resource, it will show a blank page. It might be a code issue also.

Comment: But what is the meaning of - after cleaning history it works fine for that request

Comment: It could be due to the fact that browser caches resources specific to requests. When you try to hit the same request, it first try to use the cache which may try to use some resource which is not present now due to your changes.

Comment: It will be easy to understand if you can specify what changes you  have done.

Comment: Which browser are you using ? Have you tried using some other browser?

Comment: Changes means I just add one hibernate mapping class and its related coding just one select criteria query. Bcaz of some limitation can't paste  the code

Comment: '<error-page>
 <error-code>404</error-code>
 <location>/WEB-INF/pages/404.jsp</location>
  </error-page>'
You can use the above code.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <error-page> <error-code>404</error-code> <location>/WEB-INF/pages/404.jsp</location> </error-page>
```

After adding this in web.xml, application is working fine.
Thnak you Vineet Tyagi